# Not able to retrieve hashmap from sharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap

I am retrieving list of ParseObject from Parse and casting into list of HashMap,then converting it to JSONArray and storing in SharedPrefrences as String

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        ParseObject foundObject = list.get(i);
                        HashMap<String, Object> industry = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        industry.put("CategoryName", foundObject.get("category"));
                        industry.put("lastUpdated", new Date());
                        industry.put("Jobs", foundObject.getList("jobs"));
                        data.add(industry);
                    }
                        JSONArray result = new JSONArray(data);
                        editor.putString("Categories", result.toString());
                        editor.commit();
```

Then i am retrieving from locally saved String(JSONArray)

```
String storedCollection = pref.getString("Categories", null);
        //Parse the string to populate your collection.
        collection = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        if (storedCollection != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(storedCollection);

                HashMap<String, Object> item = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject((String) array.get(i));


                        Iterator<String> it = obj.keys();

                        item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        while (it.hasNext()) {
                            String key = it.next();
                            item.put(key, obj.get(key));
                        }
                        if (item == null) {
                            JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                            Iterator<String> it1 = obj2.keys();
                            item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            while (it1.hasNext()) {
                                String key = it.next();
                                item.put(key, obj2.get(key));
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                    }
                    collection.add(item);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON", "while parsing", e);
            }
        }
```

Which works fine on and above lollipop version but giving error on lower versions

> org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 21 of
>   {jobs=[Bar management, Baker, Bar service, Barista, Car park services,
>   Chef, Cleaning services, Cooking & food preparation], lastUpdated=Tue
>   Jun 28 10:22:03 GMT+05:30 2016, category=fulltime}

and sometimes getting this error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String

Comment: I assume your Json is broken in some of the cases, thus you see the first error message. Check if the Json is correct at all.

Comment: what does your `data.add(Category);` mean? Shouldn't it be `data.add(industry);` ?

Comment: @Hao Qi Data is List of Hashmap and category is Hashmap<String,Object>

Comment: @Todor Kostov if it is broken then it wont work on above lollipop as well,isn't it?

Comment: Is that Json always the same or it is different based on some criteria? If it is different, then it is possible to be broken in some cases. The first error is more than clear.

Comment: @AniketIndulkar There was mistake in the question. Please correct it. It should be data.add(industry);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the array that you store is JSONArray of HashMaps. When you retrieve the array, the objects in the array are strings(representing HashMap). `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject((String) array.get(i));` which you are trying to convert to JSONObject.This is the problem. Either you convert each of this string back to hashmap or you can use JSONObject in place of HashMap like this to store the data

```
public void storeInPrefs(){
    JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        JSONObject industry = new JSONObject();
        ParseObject foundObject = list.get(i);
        try {
            industry.put("CategoryName", foundObject.get("category"));
            industry.put("lastUpdated", new Date());
            industry.put("Jobs", foundObject.getList("jobs"));
            data.put(industry);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    SharedPreferences preferences = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Categories", data.toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

And to parse the stored data and put it in collection, you can do this

```
public void parseStoredData(){
    SharedPreferences pref = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String storedCollection = pref.getString("Categories", null);
    //Parse the string to populate your collection.
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> collection = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    if (storedCollection != null) {
        try {

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(storedCollection);

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                try {

                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    HashMap<String,Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    Iterator<String> it = object.keys();

                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        String key = it.next();
                        item.put(key, object.get(key));
                    }

                    collection.add(item);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON", "while parsing", e);
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion this would be easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `JSONObject object = new JSONObject(industry);`

instead of `JSONArray result = new JSONArray(data);`

Thie `object.toString()` is like `{"Jobs":["Bar management","Baker","Bar service"],"lastUpdated":"Tue Jun 28 13:54:24 GMT+08:00 2016","CategoryName":"fulltime"}`

And the `result.toString()` is like `[{"Jobs":["Bar management","Baker","Bar service"],"lastUpdated":"Tue Jun 28 13:54:24 GMT+08:00 2016","CategoryName":"fulltime"}]`

I think the object is what you really want, and use JsonObject also when  retrieving.

Hope helpful.

Addtionally, you can use [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to verify your result.